# How to close modal popup based on outside click using Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ktpvah?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.html)

i am calling a component by calling its selector in other component, so it appears as popup, but i want to close that when i do outside click, can anyone help me how can that be done.

HTML Component1:

```
 <div *ngIf="editAdditionalComment">
        <app-comment></app-comment>
  </div>
```

Comment Component:

```
<div id="additionalCommentModal" class="dialog-container" keytestdirective (goListingPage)="keyDetails($event)" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" data-backdrop="static" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header bg-info">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">{{editModeData.modeHeader}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close font-lg" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="cancelChanges()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        <h6>Hello Hai</h6>
              
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Directive that I use:

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inigoClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------//

  @Output("outsideClick")
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------//

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------//

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.path'])
  public onGlobalClick(targetElementPath: Array<any>) {
    const elementRefInPath = targetElementPath.find(e => e === this._elementRef.nativeElement);
    if (!elementRefInPath) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(null);
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
  
}//Cls
```

Usage:

```
 <div inigoClickOutside (outsideClick)="onOutsideClick()"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, can you please edit in my Demo, i tried similar to this, but in my application the event is not triggering

Comment: I just looked at your stackblitz. It looks like it's already doing what you want. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a background div that recognize the click, so in your code will be like this:

```css
.div-background{
position: fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-background" (click)="editAdditionalComment = false">
<div id="additionalCommentModal" class="dialog-container" keytestdirective (goListingPage)="keyDetails($event)" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" data-backdrop="static" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header bg-info">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">{{editModeData.modeHeader}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close font-lg" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="cancelChanges()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        <h6>Hello Hai</h6>
              
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

If you need to return to the parent component the event, you can create a Output:

```js
@Output() onClickBackground = new EventEmitter()

this.onClickBackground.emit(true)
```

```html
<div *ngIf="isShowingComment">
<app-comment (onClickBackground)="isShowingComment = false"></app-comment>
</div>
```

Here is the Demo: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-z7gedp?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is not working in your demo, i have created one demo and attached with my question, can you please check and help me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ce5yso?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.scss

Comment: Thanks for response, but in my application it is not detecting that click event

Comment: I added a class style to create a transparent background, maybe it will resolve your problem. Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-z7gedp?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.html

Comment: This answer close also when you click on the modal itself. I think the answer should close the modal only when you click on the outside background